Media query to target safari browser version <= 15.x.x only
Can someone please let me know how we can target safari browser Version less than or equals 15.x.x using media query in css.
We have a bug where one element alignment is breaking in Safari Versions which are lessthan or equals to 15.x.x for other versions and browser our css is working as expected.
I have tried the query which is available in the below image but it is applying for all the versions of safari browser.
Click here for image
But it should applicable only for the versions which are lessthan or equals to 15.x.x

Would using @supports help?

supports (-webkit-hyphens:none){}. This is working for all safari versions, but i want to target only the versions which are below or equals to 15.x.x

What is it in Safari less than 15 that is breaking your site? You need to target that.

display: flex; justify-content: end..... These 2 properties are not working in the safari version 15 or below but it is working in Safari Version 16 and above.

So target one of those, or anything that was introduced in 16 - as in my answer.

subgrid was introduced in Safari 16 so this test should work:
@supports (grid-template-rows: subgrid)

